# Umbraco - Could not load type 'usercontrols_NewContactUs'

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I am trying to duplicate an existing Form in Umbraco (Contour is not installed). I have copied the following files:

**from:**
\my-site\usercontrols\Common\ContactUsForm.ascx
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="usercontrols_ContactUs" Codebehind="ContactUsForm.ascx.cs" %>

**to:**
\my-site\usercontrols\Common\NewContactUsForm.ascx
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="usercontrols_NewContactUs" Codebehind="NewContactUsForm.ascx.cs" %>

**from:**
\my-site\usercontrols\Common\ContactUsForm.ascx.cs
    public partial class usercontrols_ContactUs : System.Web.UI.UserControl {...}

**to:**
\my-site\usercontrols\Common\NewContactUsForm.ascx.cs
    public partial class usercontrols_NewContactUs : System.Web.UI.UserControl {...}

I have created a macro which points to the NewForm, and added the macro to a new page.

I don't have Visual Studio installed - could there be a compilation error in my codeBehind class?

Error details are below:

Macro created and added to form gives error:
Error creating control (usercontrols/Common/NewContactUsForm.ascx).
Maybe file doesn't exists or the usercontrol has a cache directive, which is not allowed! See the tracestack for more information!

---

> Error reading usercontrols/Common/NewContactUsForm.ascx The following
>   list shows the Public Properties from the Control. By checking the
>   Properties and click the "Save Properties" button at the bottom,
>   umbraco will create the corresponding Macro Elements.
>
> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type
>   'usercontrols_NewContactUs'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException
>   (0x80004005): Could not load type 'usercontrols_NewContactUs'. --->
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type
>   'usercontrols_NewContactUs'. at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String
>   baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly
>   assembly) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary
>   parseData) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception
>   ex) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text,
>   Encoding fileEncoding) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider
>   buildProvider) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at
>   umbraco.developer.assemblyBrowser.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it's a compilation issue. The class NewContactUsForm doesn't exist until you compile it. In a bind, you could move the code from NewContactUsForm.ascx.cs into a C# script block directly on NewContactUsForm.ascx and remove the codebehind="..." and inherits="..." refrences entirely. That way you won't have to compile.

Comment: Then shouldn't there be a dll for the original ContactUsForm in the site-root/bin folder? There is nothing with that name in the /bin folder.

Comment: No, the DLL is named after the project and contains all the classes in the project. All the code-behind stuff is compiled into one DLL.

Comment: All working now! For anyone else that needs to know, I needed to put all the 'uses' class statements in the codeBehind class into Import statements, then wrap the contents of class in a <script runat=server>...</script> block.

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import namespace="umbraco" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Utilities" %>

<script runat=server>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {...}
</script>